# Prevent GCC from optimizing away a looped write to memory mapped address

Tags: c, for-loop, gcc, volatile, 68000

I've got an address which points to a control port like so (for context I'm working on a Sega/Megadrive game):

```
volatile u32 * vdp_ctrl = (u32 *) 0x00C00004;
```

And an array of initial values I want to set:

```
const u8 initial_vdp_vals[24] = {
  0x20,
  0x74,
  0x30,
  ..etc
};
```

With a loop:

```
typedef struct {
  u16 upper;
  u8 reg;
  u8 val;
} bitset;

typedef union {
  bitset b;
  u32 as_u32;
} u_bitset;

static inline void init_vdp() {
  u_bitset cmd = {{0x00008000}};
  for(int i = 0; i < 24; i++) {
     cmd.b.val = initial_vdp_vals[i];
     *vdp_ctrl = cmd.as_u32;
     cmd.b.reg += 1;
  }
}
```

The problem is that gcc (with O2 at least) optimizes this away and only writes the last value to the `*vdp_ctrl` pointer. I've managed to get around this by setting one of the properties in the `bitset` struct to `volatile`, but that doesn't seem like an intuitive solution, and the assembly it generates as a result is *very* lengthy.

So my question is two fold:

1. What's the "correct" way to suggest to gcc that my `vdp_ctrl` pointer needs to accept multiple writes over time. I'm going to be using this pattern often (writing const/static data to control/data addresses in a loop), and marking random fields as volatile seem unintuitive.
2. The "standard of quality" I'm using for the generated asm looks like the following (not gcc generated):

```
    move.l #initial_vdp_vals, a0
    move.l #24, d0
    move.l #0x00008000, d1

.copy:
    move.b (a0)+, d1
    move.w d1, 0x00C00004
    add.w #0x0100, d1
    dbra d0, .copy
```

Which is very nice and succinct. So my other question might be (as a complete C novice): Is there a better approach to my C solution to get me closer to the assembly above? I'm not even sure if my code is correct to be honest as I'm just trying to get past this loop optimization issue first since I know it's going to be a constant issue moving forward.

Runnable example to produce my issue:

```
volatile unsigned long * vdp_ctrl = (unsigned long *) 0x00C00004;

const unsigned char initial_vdp_vals[24] = {
  0x20,
  0x74,
  0x30,
  0x40,
  0x05,
  0x70,
  0x00,
  0x00,
  0x00,
  0x00,
  0x00,
  0x08,
  0x81,
  0x34,
  0x00,
  0x00,
  0x01,
  0x00,
  0x00,
  0x00,
  0x00,
  0x00,
  0x00,
  0x00
};

typedef struct {
  unsigned int upper;
  unsigned char reg;
  unsigned char val;
} bitset;

typedef union {
  bitset b;
  unsigned long as_u32;
} u_bitset;

static inline void init_vdp() {
  u_bitset cmd = {{0x00008000}};
  for(int i = 0; i < 24; i++) {
     cmd.b.val = initial_vdp_vals[i];
     *vdp_ctrl = cmd.as_u32;
  }
}

void init() {
  init_vdp();
  for(;;) {
  }
}
```

With `m68k-linux-gnu-gcc -ffreestanding -O2 -S -c test.c -o test.s`. Generates the following:

```
#NO_APP
    .file   "test.c"
    .text
    .align  2
    .globl  init
    .type   init, @function
init:
    link.w %fp,#0
    move.l vdp_ctrl,%a0
    moveq #24,%d0
    move.l #32768,%d1
.L2:
    move.l %d1,(%a0)
    subq.l #1,%d0
    jne .L2
.L3:
    jra .L3
    .size   init, .-init
    .globl  initial_vdp_vals
    .section    .rodata
    .type   initial_vdp_vals, @object
    .size   initial_vdp_vals, 24
initial_vdp_vals:
    .byte   32
    .byte   116
    .byte   48
    .byte   64
    .byte   5
    .byte   112
    .byte   0
    .byte   0
    .byte   0
    .byte   0
    .byte   0
    .byte   8
    .byte   -127
    .byte   52
    .byte   0
    .byte   0
    .byte   1
    .byte   0
    .byte   0
    .byte   0
    .byte   0
    .byte   0
    .byte   0
    .byte   0
    .globl  vdp_ctrl
    .data
    .align  2
    .type   vdp_ctrl, @object
    .size   vdp_ctrl, 4
vdp_ctrl:
    .long   12582916
    .ident  "GCC: (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1) 7.4.0"
    .section    .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

```
gcc version 7.4.0 (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1)
```

**Note**: It does appear the size of my array determines if it gets optimized out or not. When I made it only two elements it did not optimize out.

Comment: Show a [mre] and specify the compiler version and all compiler switches you are using so other people can reproduce the behavior.

Comment: I agree that would be useful. I'll try to get a working example thrown together.

Comment: Note the assembly might be a bit simpler if you can define the address as `volatile uint32_t * const vdp_ctrl;`. Probably not related to whether it produces a loop.

Comment: Wont that give me warnings when trying to write to it?

Comment: No, because the constant here will be the address that is being pointed to, not the contents of that location.

Comment: I've added a working example which reproduces my results.

Comment: How big is `unsigned long` on your platform? Is it bigger than `unsigned int`?

Comment: char 8, int 16, long 32

Comment: Did you check that? I get sizeof(int)==sizeof(long)==4 with that m68k compiler, unless I pass `-mshort`...

Comment: Isn't `u_bitset cmd = {{0x00008000}};` equal to `u_bitset cmd = {.b.upper = {0x00008000}};`? You meant to `u_bitset cmd = {.as_u32 = {0x00008000}};`? You want equivalent of `*vdp_ctrl = 0x00008000 | (initial_vdp_vals[i] << 24)`?

Comment: @MarcGlisse You are absolutely right. That's a mistake. I believe you may have found the issue as it appears the code is no longer optimized away after passing the `-mshort` flag.

Comment: @MarcGlisse If you'd like to post an answer I'd love to mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

In this kind of code you shuold use exact size integers. I strongly advice to pack the structures and unions as well.

```
#include <stdint.h>
#define vdp_ctrl  ((volatile uint32_t *) 0x00C00004)

const unsigned char initial_vdp_vals[24] = {
  0x20,
  0x74,
  0x30,
  0x40,
  0x05,
  0x70,
  0x00,
  0x00,
  0x00,
  0x00,
  0x00,
  0x08,
  0x81,
  0x34,
  0x00,
  0x00,
  0x01,
  0x00,
  0x00,
  0x00,
  0x00,
  0x00,
  0x00,
  0x00
};

typedef struct {
  uint16_t upper;
  uint8_t reg;
  uint8_t val;
} __attribute__((packed)) bitset;

typedef union {
  bitset b;
  uint32_t as_u32;
} __attribute__((packed)) u_bitset ;

static inline void init_vdp() {
  u_bitset cmd = {.b.upper = 0x00008000};
  for(int i = 0; i < 24; i++) 
  {
     cmd.b.val = initial_vdp_vals[i];
     *vdp_ctrl = cmd.as_u32;
  }
}

void init() {
  init_vdp();
  for(;;) {
  }
}
```

and it generates the code you need.

IMO it better yo have macro instead of the real object. It may not make any difference in this trivial code, but it will if the code becomes more complicated.

Comment: Don't use packed. It is completely unnecessary, and tells the compiler that the object need not be aligned, which can make it use much larger/worse code to access and mess up atomicity of volatile accesses.

Comment: when we pune packed data it is necessary, so please do not use such a strong- teacher style comments. this comment is 100% wrong. uC data very often has to be packed

Comment: It does **not** have to be packed unless the actual layout has misaligned fields, which this doesn't. Just throwing packed at everything rather than using it where it's actually needed both generates worse (larger/slower) code **and** can actually break things.

Comment: Where it does change the code - it will be needed. BTW atomicity, coherency and volatile access etc etc is not affected by packing. It is a myth.

Comment: No it will not! If you declare an object of the type, it will no longer be aligned and will thereby have to generate more code to access it. Moreover, if you then take the address of members and pass them to functions taking a pointer to the member type, they will malfunction/fault because they rightly expect aligned objects but receive a pointer to an unaligned one.